# Javascript - Magnific Popup not working when HTML Elements are generated using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, magnific-popup

I have a problem regarding the magnific popup, so whenever i type the code in HTML, its working but whenever I try using Javascript to generate the HTML element that have popup menu, the popup not appear.

Here my HTML Code to show the popup using HTML Code and its working

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
    <body>
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="right-content">
        <div class="right-content-row profile">
            <h6>Welcome,</h6>
            <p><b id='customer_email' name ='customer_email'></b></p>
            <!--You are being served by <br><br> <b id ='emp_name' name='emp_name'></b>-->
        </div>
                    <div class="right-content-row order-total">
            TOTAL <span>150</span>
        </div>
        <div class="right-content-row poweredby">
            <p>POWERED BY <span class="logo-ifabula" onClick="document.location='http://ifabula.com'" style="cursor:pointer"></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="left-side">
    <div class="top-nav">
        <ul id='tab' name='tab'>

        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="sub-nav">
        <ul id='tab_child' name='tab_child'>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="left-side-content">
        <div class="catalog-content">
            <b id='prod_item'></b>
            <div id='prod_item_display'>

            </div>  
            <!--<h1>Raciones</h1> -->
            <b id='ts'>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-product">
                    <img src="http://localhost/tapas//img/prod_gallery/Aglio_Salmon_thumb.jpg">
                    <h2>Aglio Salmon</h2>
                    <p class="price">70,000</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#popup-product" class="open-popup-link">
                    <img src="images/img-product.jpg" />
                    <h2>Olives</h2>
                    <p class="price">30</p> 
                </a></li>
            </ul>
            </b>


        </div>
        <p class="footnote" style="display:none;">All prices in thousand Indonesian Rupiah. Prices can be change in anytime without notice. Tax & Service charges are not included!</p>
    </div>

</div>
<p id='popup_item' name='popup_item'></b>
<div id="popup-product" class="popup-product mfp-hide">
    <div class="popup-product-img">
        <img src="images/img-product.jpg" />
        <h1>Bread with Tomato Sauce & Iberico Ham</h1>
    </div>
    <p class="popup-product-description">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.</p>
    <div class="popup-product-option">
        QUANTITY &nbsp; <input id="down" onClick="setQuantity('down');" type="button" class="minus" /> <input id="quantity" type="text" value="1" min="0" /> <input id="up" onClick="setQuantity('up');" type="button" class="plus" /> <input type="submit" value="ORDER" />
    </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>     
<!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script> -->
<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="js/catalog2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="js/default.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.jscrollpane.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.smartCart-2.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here the Javascript code to generate the list of item from JSON Return and the popup is not working

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "http://127.0.0.1/menu/menu_controller/display_child_item/"+child_category_id[item_child],
                    data : "CategoryUUID="+child_category_id,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(result_item)
                    {
                        for (var prod_item in result_item)
                        {
                            x = x+1;
                            if(x == 1)
                            {

                                prod_display.push('<h1>'+child_name[0]+'</h1>');
                                prod_display.push('<ul>');

                                prod_display.push("<li><a class='open-popup-link' href='#popup-product'><img src='http://localhost/tapas/"+result_item[prod_item].image_thumbnail.toString()+"'/><h2>"+result_item[prod_item].product_name.toString()+"</h2><p class='price'>"+numberWithCommas(result_item[prod_item].price.toString())+"</p></a></li>");                                      
                                popup_product.push('<div id="popup-product'+result_item[prod_item].ProductUUID.toString()+'" class="popup-product mfp-hide"><div class="popup-product-img"><img src="images/img-product.jpg" /> <h1>Bread with Tomato Sauce & Iberico Ham</h1></div><p class="popup-product-description">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.</p><div class="popup-product-option">      QUANTITY &nbsp; <input id="down"  type="button" class="minus" /> <input id="quantity" type="text" value="1" min="0" /> <input id="up"  type="button" class="plus" /> <input type="submit" value="ORDER" /></div></div>');       
                            }
                            else if(x != 1)
                            {
                                prod_display.push('<li><a id="test" class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-product" class="open-popup-link"><img src="http://localhost/tapas/'+result_item[prod_item].image_thumbnail.toString()+'"/><h2>'+result_item[prod_item].product_name.toString()+'</h2><p class="price">'+numberWithCommas(result_item[prod_item].price.toString())+'</p></a></li>');                                        
                                popup_product.push('<div id="popup-product'+result_item[prod_item].ProductUUID.toString()+'" class="popup-product mfp-hide"><div class="popup-product-img"><img src="images/img-product.jpg" /> <h1>Bread with Tomato Sauce & Iberico Ham</h1></div><p class="popup-product-description">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.</p><div class="popup-product-option">      QUANTITY &nbsp; <input id="down"  type="button" class="minus" /> <input id="quantity" type="text" value="1" min="0" /> <input id="up"  type="button" class="plus" /> <input type="submit" value="ORDER" /></div></div>');                           

                            }

                        }
                        prod_display.push('</ul>');


                        document.getElementById("prod_item_display").innerHTML = prod_display.join('');

                    }
```

COuld you please help me to find out what is the solution for this. Already do countless trial and errors but no luck :(

Comment: add magnific popup event .on which element  click you want to  open magnific popup

Comment: Ah i see. Yeah i think thats the root cause. Well thank you anyway for your insight.  Another thing is how can i show the popup for each list of items which are returned by JSON  ?

Comment: you need to convert json data in to dom element. then assign event as in mention in my answer .. if my answer help you thne vote or accept answer

Comment: Could you please give me some sample code for better understanding ?

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2a6a4gvh/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code .it is [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) isue

```
$(document).on('click', '.open-popup-link',function(){
  var popupSRC = $(this).parent('li').next('div.popup-product');
  $.magnificPopup.open({
      items: {
          src: popupSRC,
      },
      type: 'inline'
  });
});
```